# How to collect each parameter of a function in an array?

Tags: c++

I am currently in a code optimization phase and I would need help: I have a large number of functions taking as parameters `std::string`s and in which these `std::string`s are transformed in `double`s using `std::stod`. I would like to be able to create a "gateway" function that would allow all the parameters of the function to be changed at once. I had thought of a function using variadic templates. Can you help me, please? This is an example of one of my functions:

```cpp
std::optional<d> rectangle(const std::string& length, const std::string& width) {
    if (others::is_type<double>(length) && others::is_type<double>(width)) {
        d length_ = stod(length);
        d width_ = stod(width);
        return std::round((length_ * width_) * options::rounder) / options::rounder;
    }
    return {};
}
```

If you want me to add more details or to detail the other functions used in this one, ask me in comments. I already thank the all of you who'll answer.

To answer the first comment : the gateway function would collect the parameters of an other function (I don't know how for the moment), verify that they are strings and then to convert them to double. The aim would be to be able to just use this function and not to write "double ... = stod(...)" all the time (cause I have a really big number of functions).

Comment: Suppose you had this "gateway function". How would you use it and what would it do exactly?

Comment: I answered you editing my post @interjay

Comment: Why don't you change the functions to accept `double` parameters (maybe `optional<double>`) and shift the responsibility for conversion to the caller?

Comment: What does this have to do with collecting parameters in an array?

Comment: JaMiT you're totally right. I think that's what I'm going to do. interjay I think I took the problem on the wrong side. Thanks for your answers, I'll try to do it on my own now.